# Setting up Gulp with NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, gulp

I'm trying to setup Gulp on Netbeans but am getting the following error

> Local gulp not found in ~

I have added my Gulp Path which is "/usr/local/bin/gulp", and I can't find anymore information on using Gulp with Netbeans.

I am ideally trying to setup an environment where I can use my gulp tasks across multiple projects through Netbeans to process postCSS and maybe some CSS and Javascript minification etc. before deploying.

Any ideas or resources I can use?

Comment: Have you added gulp as a project dependency? See #2 in https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: Yes I started a new blank project and created a new gulpfile within netbeans which contains

var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    // place code for your default task here
});

Comment: npm isn't working either. Looks like both are looking in my user folder but the project is located in the htdocs folder of MAMP. How do i change the directory for gulp and npm in netbeans?

`npm ERR! path /Users/Jonny/package.json`

Comment: Do you have a package.json in your project folder in the same folder as gulpfile? Does the package.json have gulp as a dependency and did you run npm install in the project? NetBeans are executing any nodejs related command (npm, gulp, grunt...) in context of the project folder.

Comment: Yes to all. The same project works fine when I use sublime text and the terminal to run gulp

Answer (score 2):

First link gulp:

```
sudo npm link gulp
```

and add node_modules to gitignore

```
echo 'node_modules/' >> .gitignore
```

Now you can use gulp in Netbeans.